# Java number sum

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have code who makes random numbers and prints them. And it counts numbers who are bigger than 250. How can I output in a one number? I need sum the results numbers.

Like this:

> 315   32  486 311 58
>
> 430   145 83  395 312
>
> 223   455 370 151 84
>
> 163   415 433 75  194
>
> 152   457 427 218 301
>
> 142   298 300 404 24
>
> 15    296 368 196 438
>
> 102   410 351 341 328

results:

> 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 4

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (ch=='Y' || ch=='y') {
            for (i=0; i<8; i++)
                for (j=0; j<5; j++) 
                    A[i][j] = rnd.nextInt((500 - 10) + 1) + 10;

        }
        else
            if (ch != 'N' && ch != 'n') {
                System.out.println("input-output error");
                return;
            }

        for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<5; j++)
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("results: ");
        for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
            res = 0;
            for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] >= 250) res++;

            }

                System.out.print((res) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the numbers that are greater than threshold in the loop that prints them, like this:

```
    int res = 0;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
            if (A[i][j] >= 250) res++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("results: " + res);
```